# Fourier Transform of f(x) = cos(3x-2)

Tags: fourier-transform

I was thinking of using the same approach as is stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276392/fourier-transform-of-sin3x-using-a-delta-relation) but I believe that wont work due to the 3x-2. I'm trying to use the trigonometric identity for sin(A-B) = sin(A)cos(B) - cos(A)sin(B), but I somehow am confusing myself in the middle. Any thoughts or hints would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possibly worth reading -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2563176/correct-answer-for-fourier-transform-of-cosatb?rq=1

Comment: I see, so I just need to substitute in the identity for sin(A-B) right?